# generar txt con caracteres especiales php

Tags: php

tengo mi codigo que genera archivos .txt

```
<?php

$fi = fopen("archivo.txt", "a") or die ("Problemas al crear archivo");

$nom = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$com = $_REQUEST['comentario'];

fwrite($fi, "Datos: ");
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi,$nom);
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi,$com);
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi, "----------------------------------------------------- \n \n");
fclose($fi);
echo "Archivo guardado";
?>
```

Mi problema que al guardar caracteres especiales los guarda asi :

```
"ðŸŒðŸ¬ÊŸá´‡á´›'s É¢á´ á´ÉªsÉªá´É´á´‡sðŸ¬ðŸŒ 
á¶œáµ’áµáµ˜â¿â±áµˆáµƒáµˆ áµ’á¶ â±á¶œâ±áµƒË¡ Ë¡áµ‰áµ—'Ë¢ áµáµ’"
```

el original es este:

```
ᴍɪsɪᴏɴᴇs
   ᶜᵒᵐᵘⁿⁱᵈᵃᵈ
▪️Lugar: Sidney
```

alguien podria ayudarme?

gracias de antemano, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que deberías grabar el fichero en formato UTF-8.

Mira aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format

Comment: funciono, gracias